from dēfēcisse to deficisse
My question concerns the forms dēfēcisse (dēficio, active infinitive perfect) and the variant dēficisse. I found both forms in a text from Justin/Trogus (Epitome.11.2.7) :

In cuius apparatu occupato nuntiatur Athenienses et Lacedaemonios ab
eo ad Persas defecisse auctoremque eius defectionis magno auri pondere
a Persis corruptum Demosthenem oratorem extitisse, [...]


deficisse in the Bude edition;
defecisse in the Latin Library edition and in a dissertation about Justin/Trogus text.

Nothing in the critical apparatus of these editions helps me to distinguish the two forms.
I analyze dēficisse as a late variant of dēfēcisse, dēficisse being built on the theme of the present (dēfic-) instead of being built on the theme of the perfect (dēfēc-). About this analyse,see by example this document (in Spanish, §60+note 105) on a late Latin text.
I have three questions:
(1) Is my analysis of dēficisse correct?
(2) When did this variant appear? In particular, did this variant already exist in Classical Latin?
(3) How long is the first -i- in dēficisse? Is there a poetic text or an inscription showing the quantity of the first -i- in dēficisse?

It sounds like you found your answer to the first two questions in the literature, I'm not sure what you'd like us to add to it. For the third, the i in deficisse can only be short regardless of the source, because it would be a product of vowel weakening.
